# How can I diagnose this memory leak that crashes site on mobile devices

Tags: firebase, vue.js, webpack, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

We are pulling our hair out... this app is build with firestore, vuejs, vuetify, webpack and is very similar to a dozen others that we have. It works perfectly on a computer browser, but it crashes almost immediately when you open it up on a mobile phone.

We've scrubbed the code as much as we can to clean up leaks but the site is still unusable. It's really not even that complicated of an app.

When I take a snapshot, the app uses 1028 of Memory.

Can anyone help us diagnose the problem?

http://staffbeats.com

Thanks!

Comment: This webapp is in development mode (regarding vue) and also using Firebase development build. There is no point investigating memory leaks in such a context. deploy your app as you would in production, use Chrome with a clean profile (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/clean-testing-environment) and then start looking for memory retainers or eventlisteners not being removed

Comment: I went ahead and switched firebase... vue is still in development thought. There is a known issue with changing to a production environment https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/535

Comment: You should consider starting your project from scratch again using Vue-cli 3 instead of that deprecated template. Then just copy/paste your components to your new project